# accesing data objects in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a data() object in my Maincomponent.vue. In that data() i have an array called myDatabase and it has several objects. I want to access the fields in myDatabase using methods
I want to toggle the isPreview to false and true on click

```
data() {
      return {

          myDatabase: [
              {
                  id: 1,
                  name: "Blue",
                  fabric: require("../static/images/blue.jpeg"),
                  previewImage: require("../static/images/blue-shirt.jpeg"),
                  isPreview: true
              },
              {
                  id: 2,
                  name: "Black",
                  fabric: require("../static/images/black.jpeg"),
                  previewImage: require("../static/images/black-shirt.jpeg"),
                  isPreview: false
              }

            ]
        } 
    },

    methods: {
       showPreview: function() {
           return this.myDatabase.isPreview == false ? true : false
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [documentation about methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Handling-User-Input) :

Example :

```html
<template>
  <p>{{ myDatabase[0].isPreview }}</p>
  <button @click="reversePreview(1)">Reverse preview</button>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  data () { 
    return {
      myDatabase: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Blue",
        fabric: require("../static/images/blue.jpeg"),
        previewImage: require("../static/images/blue-shirt.jpeg"),
        isPreview: true
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Black",
        fabric: require("../static/images/black.jpeg"),
        previewImage: require("../static/images/black-shirt.jpeg"),
        isPreview: false
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    reversePreview (id) {
      const index = this.myDatabase.findIndex(db => db.id === id)
      this.myDatabase[index].isPreview = !this.myDatabase[index].isPreview
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: this throws an error: this.myDatabase[index] is undefined

Comment: The `id` in `reversePreview (id)` should match an `id` from `myDatabase`